# How do we use iOS bit code support with React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

We are using React Native for a feature in an existing iOS app. We would like to use iOS app thinning and bit code support to keep the download size down. The React Native libraries don’t seem to support compilation of bit code. Has anyone had success with this approach? Is it on the ReactNative RoadMap?